# Snapping Polygon vertices to Point features using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, gps, arcgis-engine, vertices

I have a set of polygons drawn using an inaccurate GPS PDA. these polygons are sharing nodes.

After post-processing GPS data to get accurate coordinates i have a set of all the nodes, then i have to update the vertices of already drawn polygons. the relation between old and new vertices is based on the nearest point.

How could i modify polygon vertices in this case, using ArcGIS Engine , ArcObjects or just ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: This is very powerful tool indeed i really found it handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Snap (Editing)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000007000000.htm) tool from ArcToolbox. It can be found in `ArcToolbox\Editing\Snap`.

Set inaccurate polygons as `Input features` and accurate points after post-processing as `Snapping Environment`. Also set reasonable `Distance` parameter for points.

Result of my testing the tool:
[image: result1]

This tool is only available with ArcEditor and ArcInfo licenses.